# How to sum up total amount in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express

i was trying to get total(sum up) amount in mongodb data on express js

[image: orders collections]

with this code

```
const Order = require("../models/Order")
const { verifyToken, verifyTokenAndAuth, verifyTokenAndAdmin } = require("./verifyToken")
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const router = require("express").Router()
const template = require('../utils/nota')
   router.get("/pendapatan", async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const countAmount = Order.db.collection('orders').aggregate([ {
                $group: { 
                    _id: null, 
                    "amount": { 
                        $sum: "$amount" 
                    } 
                } 
            }]);
            res.json(countAmount)
            console.log(countAmount)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json(error)
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
```

but it return empty

Answer (score 0):

The Order.db.collection('orders').aggregate([...]) call returns a cursor, which is a pointer to the result of the aggregation. To access the actual result, the await keyword is needed to ensure that the aggregation operation is completed and the result is retrieved before proceeding. Without await, the code might move on before the aggregation finishes.